# asp.net web api internal server error 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

On my local server it returns json but when I publish it to remote server. I get 500 internal server error.

I can't run the hosted site in debug mode, on local host it seems fine. The remote server is IIS8.5 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 and my local IIS is iis 8

The html response is 
500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Api Controller

```
public class loginapiController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public UserProjects UserProjects(int id)
    {
        return new UserProjects(id);
    }
}

public class UserProjects
{
    public IEnumerable<Project> Projects = new List<Project>();
    public List<Project> ExistingUserProjects = new List<Project>();
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public UserProjects(int userId)
    {
        UserId = userId;
        var context = new AuditConnection();
        var existingProjectIds = context.UserProjects.Where(up => up.UserId == userId).Select(p => p.ProjectId);
        foreach (var id in existingProjectIds)
        {
            var project = context.Projects.Where(p => p.ProjectId == id).First();
            ExistingUserProjects.Add(project);
        }

        var proj = context.Projects.ToList();
        Projects = proj.Except(ExistingUserProjects);
    }
}
```

You can look at the exception using this link http://sentry.landsea.com.au/api/loginapi/UserProjects/4

Comment: You can use logging to locate the problem, But my guess is a connection string issue.

Comment: There are other actions which are running fine. Other actions query the same database. So i guess the connection string is fine. I will be looking at the log. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Take a look at windows event log to get more detailed information about the error on the hosted server. There 1 million reason for a 500 error. It could be databse, it could be something else

Comment: you can see the exception at this following link sentry.landsea.com.au/api/loginapi/UserProjects/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: given the error

> "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062192/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-c#6064422) will explain your issue. Your best bet is to let your Reader finish the first command before starting another (you could do this with `ToList()`), or collapse the query down to a single call (I believe that you could do this by refactoring your queries into one which uses `SelectMany()`).

Keep in mind that [turning on MARS may be covering up a bigger problem](http://devproconnections.com/development/solving-net-scalability-problem), and you should understand it fully before you go that route, especially for a web application with the lifetime scope of your DbContext should be setup as the life of a single http request. Doing that is trivial if you're properly manually disposing of your context or if you're using a dependency injection framework.

Comment: I am using web deploy. I have other actions querying the same database using the same connection string with out any problem.

you can see the exception at this following link http://sentry.landsea.com.au/api/loginapi/UserProjects/4

Answer (score 0):

For me the URL shows a clear error message: `"Message":"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."` You can only have one DataReader open at once, so the code has to be fixed.