# How to use JSON.NET to serialize an array of objects

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

I remember that one of my friends told me that I can throw anything into JSON.NET and serialize them into JSON format.

```
    public string GetRecords(string apiKey, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Id == apiKey);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var records = db.Histories.Where(h => h.Date >= start && h.Date <= end);

        JavaScriptSerializer s = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(records);
    }
```

But now I got an exception:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
> must be closed first.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `.ToList()` on records, before passing it to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't enable multiple active result sets (MARS) in your config file.

Follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Basically need to add

```
"MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
```

Or you could eager load as suggested by 3dd

More help here [There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062192/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-c)