# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first (ASP.NET MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have some code in loop:

```
foreach (var report in reports)
{
    var Current_Project = db.Projects.Where(c_p => c_p.project_name == report.pcode).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

When I run it, it shows message error:

> > There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Even when I put

```
var Current_Project = db.Projects.FirstOrDefault();
```

When I try to put it outside of the loop, it works.

Please, advice.

Comment: Take a look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062192/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-c)

Comment: You have to enable `MARS` as a workaround. But it is more likely your code is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is given by  [Daniel J.G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1836935/daniel-j-g)

"Add MultipleActiveResultSets=true to the provider part of your connection string"

Everything works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in your application you are using `datareader` and you have not close it that is why error is coming,connection with database is still open that is why error is coming.

Use this to close datareader:

```
datareader.Close();
```