# How to do bulkinsert in batches with EF core and BulkExtensions

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The following code reads data from a SQL database, does some calculations then enters those results in a different SQL databse. I'm trying to get it to work as fast as possible with millions of data points and the main bottleneck seems to be actually saving the database.

```
    Pipe_Context dbContext = new Pipe_Context(Configuration["ConnectionString"], calculationType);

    PipeProbabilityModel eng = new PipeProbabilityModel(CB_Mit_Factor, calculationType);

    int count = 0;

    List<OutputTable> lst = new List<OutputTable>();


    try
    {
        foreach (var pipe in dbContext.AssetServices)
        {

            double risk = eng.calculate(pipe.Diameter,pipe.Material,pipe.InstallationType);


            OutputTable newItem = new OutputTable();
            newItem.AssetId = pipe.Id;
            newItem.PCb = risk;
            newItem.CoR = (risk * pipe.LocationType);

            lst.Add(newItem);

            if(count % 1000000 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Here");
                dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdate(lst);
                lst.Clear();
            }
            ++count;
    }catch (System.InvalidOperationException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: The database contains duplicate keys, Abort");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("info: Total " + count.ToString() + " entries has been added");

    dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdate(lst);
```

The problem is when I have above a million pipes it throws a System.InvalidOperationException and doesn't continue to execute. Without the catch block it throws `Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`
Is there a way to run bulkinsertorupdate in batches or a better way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Move the try to the beginning of the code.  I do not think that exception is occurring in the for loop.  Because you are getting the exception before the for loop and you do not have a exception handler at the beginning of the code it is reporting the exception in the only exception handler in the routine.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the advice but it's happening the for loop

Comment: See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062192/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-c