# How can I set a timeout om my query on LinqPad on ExecuteQueryDynamic?

Tags: c#, linqpad

How can I set a timeout om my query on LinqPad on ExecuteQueryDynamic?

```
Util.CurrentDataContext.ExecuteQueryDynamic($"SELECT count(*) FROM MyDb.dbo.{viewName}");
```

I would like to use this timeout to detect the too slow views. For each view I request a count but when my count take too much time I just stop it and count the next one.

Here is my full LINQPad code

```
void Main()
{
    // In case of error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."
    // https://stackoverflow.com/q/6062192/196526
    // Add MultipleActiveResultSets=true to connection string. 

    var biewsCount = b.V_sysobjects.Where(v => v.Type == "V").Count();
    var bViewsDetail = Util.OnDemand<List<SysObject>>("Get Views Detail", () => GetViewsDetail("b", b.V_sysobjects.Where(v => v.Type == "V").Select(v => v.Name).ToList()));
    bViewsDetail.Dump();
}

public List<SysObject> GetViewsDetail(string database, List<string> objectNames)
{
    var result = new List<SysObject>();
    foreach (var name in objectNames)
    {
        Console.Write($"{database}.dbo.{name}");
        // I should add a timeout stuff here or before
        var count = (int)Util.CurrentDataContext.ExecuteQueryDynamic($"SELECT count(*) FROM {database}.dbo.{name}").Select(y => y).Single();
        Console.Write($" {count}\n");
        result.Add(new SysObject
        {
            Database = database,
            ObjectName = name,
            Rows = count
        });
    }
    return result;
}

public class SysObject
{
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }
    public string ObjectType { get; set; }
    public string IndexName { get; set; }
    public long Rows { get; set; }
    public long? TotalPages { get; set; }
    public long? UsedPages { get; set; }
    public long? DataPages { get; set; }
    public long? TotalSpaceMB { get; set; }
    public long? UsedSpaceMB { get; set; }
    public long? DataSpaceMB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Like `Util.CurrentDataContext.CommantTimeout`?

Comment: Not changing anything

Comment: Are you using EntityFramework?

Comment: @Arif Is use LINQPad so I'm using Entity Framework

Comment: Did you have any properties like `Util.CurrentDataContext.Database.CommandTimeout` ?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in LINQPad. The `ExecuteQueryDynamic` method should honor the `DataContext`'s `CommandTimeout`.

This has now been fixed (as of 5.37.4, currently in beta).

Note that `Util.CurrentDataContext` is redundant unless the containing method is static. The `Select(y=>y)` is also redundant. So in your example, you can just do this:

```
CommandTimeout = 1;
var count = (int)ExecuteQueryDynamic($"SELECT count(*) FROM {database}.dbo.{name}").Single();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, apart from setting the command or connection timeouts in the client, there is no way to change timeouts on a query in the server.

You can try this way, that works fine for me:

Just before running your actual query, set it for your query

```
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 1000;   --1 second
```

and after running your query set it back to original value. The default value for running query is **600** seconds.