# Entity Framework runtime error - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have a sample application with the following models and context-

```
   public class Department
   {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
   }

   public class Student
   {
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }

     public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
   }
 public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the progarm.cs code. When i debug and the debugger reach - Consol.WriteLine method inside foreach block, i get the error-  **There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first**. Why is that. Should not context close automatically once it opens connection when the foreach code is reached.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new TestContext())
        {
            var students = context.Students.Where(s => s.Id == 1);

            foreach (var student in students)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Student : {0} - Department {1}", student.Name, student.Department.Name);
            }

            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062192/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-c)

Comment: @marsze - yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you have your `TestContext` wrapped in a `using` statement which means that the `TestContext` will remain open until the end of the `using` statement.

Your initial call  is essentially a query which only gets executed when your `foreach` loop is hit:

```
var students = context.Students.Where(s => s.Id == 1);
```

This is causing the error. I.e., it is resulting in multiple queries on a `DataReader` that does not allow it.

@Arman is correct: `.ToList()` will solve your problem because the query is being executed to get all the students to a list before the `foreach` loop. Obviously, there are a number of solutions to this problem. Probably the most common one would be set [MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-ver15) to true on your connection string; i.e.:

```
Server={myServer};Initial Context={myDb};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;…
```

This will allow multiple open `DataReaders`.

Answer (score 1):

This issue raises due to this in foreach loop: `student.Department.Name`.

In fact here you have one DataReader associated with foreach loop and one associated with loading `Department`

Change retrieval this way and your problem should be solved:

```
var students = context.Students.Where(s => s.Id == 1).Include(s => s.Department).ToList();
```

Comment: With the added include, you might not need to call `ToList` explicitly