# .NET 6 Console App: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, console, .net-6.0

I'm working with .NET 6 console app.
I have Program.cs where the DBContext is instantiated.

```
public class Program
{
    static ProcedureService procservice;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        string onlineConnectionString = "Server = localhost; Database = DB; Trusted_Connection = True;";

        services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(ConnectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        services.AddScoped<ProcedureService , ProcedureService>();
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        procservice = serviceProvider.GetService<ProcedureService>();
    }
}
```

I also have an internal class that would call another service to do the logic and save something on the DB.

the service looks like this

```
public class Service
{
    ProcedureService procservice;

    public Service(ProcedureService procservice)
    {
        this.procservice = procservice;
    }
}
```

and inside this service I have a method who also calls the ProcedureService and that's the time I had encounter "A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed."

ProcedureService

```
public ProcedureService(DBContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Comment: change from `ServiceLifetime.Transient` to `ServiceLifetime.Scopped`

Comment: This error means you are using same instance of DbContext concurrently, either from multiple threads, or from the same thread but without awaiting asynchronous operations.

Comment: why are you not injecting `DBContext` through constructor in class `ProcedureService ?'

Comment: There is not enough information to diagnose what is happening here. You can use the same instance of `DbContext` concurrently which will lead to he described behaviour. Or do something like was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74892134/2501279). Please share the code showing the `DbContext` usage where the exception is thrown.